# touch & touch and hold in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a embedded webview in my app with a navbar and a uitabbar. when i touch and hold the uiwebview the copy,paste menu appears. Can i handle a single touch to show and hide my navbar and uitabbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

-webkit-touch-callout: none;

in CSS